# Addign an Event for another WB from a module

Tags: vba, excel, events

This question might have been answered already but I cant seem to find the answer I am looking for. I am creating a module which when called it creates a new workbook and transfers information from this workbook to the new one. I would like to add an event to that new work book using this macro but had no luck. Currently I have the following:

```
Public Sub TemplateCreate()
Dim NewBook as Workbook
set NewBook = addnew
End Sub

Function Addnew() as Object
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 2
Application.EnableEvents = True
Set AddNew = Workbooks.Add
    With AddNew
        .SaveAs Filename:="test.xls"
    End With
End function
```

The Above code works great, but when Adding dim withEvents Newbook as workbook I receive an error: Only valid on Object module. Is there a similar line of code to make it work for a module?

I tried adding the following event function with no luck of making it work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Tried changing between target and thisWB
If thisWB.Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Count = 1 And IsEmpty(thisWB.Sheets("sheet1")) Then thisWB.Sheets("sheet1").Interior.Color = vbBlue
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will need to create a class to manage the event capture.  See here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx  about half-way down the page.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in this direction. However I do have a question, it talks about creating a class but also mentions that I will need to add the withEvent object but it wont be possible to add this since i am adding everything on the module, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

In Class module named "clsWB":

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_wb As Workbook

Public Property Set Workbook(wb As Workbook)
    Set m_wb = wb
End Property

'EDIT: added Getter for workbook
Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
    Set Workbook = m_wb
End Property

Private Sub m_wb_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "You selected " & Target.Address() & " on '" & Sh.Name & "'"
    '... or however you want to respond to the trapped event
End Sub

'EDIT2: trap sheet changes
Private Sub m_wb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "You changed " & Target.Address() & _
           " to " & Target.Value & _
           " on '" & Sh.Name & "'"
    '... or however you want to respond to the trapped event
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWb As New clsWB

Sub Tester()
    Dim AddNew As Workbook, ns As Long

    ns = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook 'save default
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 2
    Set AddNew = Workbooks.Add()
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = ns 'restore previous default

    AddNew.SaveAs Filename:="test.xls"

    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure events are enabled
    Set oWb.Workbook = AddNew

    'EDIT: set value in workbook
    oWb.Workbook.Sheets("sheet2").Cells(x,y).Value = "Test"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this example! It helps me a lot. I have a question regarding this new workbook class, before creating the class when NewBook was created as a workbook, I could use NewBook.Sheets("sheet2"). Now after making Newbook as new clsWB, I tried NewBook.Workbook.Sheets("sheet2") and receive a invalid use of property error, why is it that I cant use .workbook.sheets?

Comment: Do you mean `AddNew` ?  That reference should work as long as you're within the Tester sub.   If you want to reference the workbook later, you can add a Getter to the class to return the Workbook property so you can work with it.  I'll update my code a little later to show how that would look.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to use owb.workbook.sheets("sheet2").cell(x,y).value to get the cell value or set the cell value. Ive tried using the following getter : `code` Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
    Workbook = m_wb
End Property

Comment: But i get an error saying the variable has not been set. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Awesome that did it! I was missing the set workbook part. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I had one last question regarding this, will the class keep the event listening all the time? it seems to be only doing it when the module is run and then when i try to do something manually on the worksheets nothing happens

Comment: It should keep listening as long as the oWB object is in-scope and there's no other problem with your code such as an error which ends up resetting the VBA project state.

Comment: Great! I ve noticed that I am only able to add worbook related events on this class is there a way to add for example a change event so that it shows me which cell was changed? instead of a wokbook_sheetChange?