# VBA: Rename a copied worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, default, renaming

I have this line of code that copies a worksheet to a new workbook:

```
OrderForm.Copy ' copy worksheet to new workbook
```

The new workbook shows up as Book*n*.xlsx:
[image]

---

When saving this is what shows up:
[image]

I'm okay if it shows up as Book*n* on the title bar and I don't want to automatically save it, but what I want is to have a default name (also default to .xlsx) when the user decides to save it, like this:

[image]

Comment: Look into `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BeforeSave event to capture the user saving, then show your own dialog with an initial value (like so):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fName As String

    Cancel = True

    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Default Name", _
        "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
        "Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *xlsm")
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fName
End Sub
```

Comment: Where would I put this? As I've mentioned I want it to apply to the workbook that gets created when my macro runs the code OrderForm.Copy.

Comment: @PuggyLongLegs Try building off the code here: (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428213-programmatically-inserting-worksheet-change-event.html). It shows how you could add code to a different module, eg the new workbook you create. Else you could create your own event handling class and instance it with an event-bound reference to the new workbook. Something like: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686542/addign-an-event-for-another-wb-from-a-module)